# Is my use case for apollo graphql subscriptions warranted?

Tags: graphql, apollo

**Preface:**

I'm working on an education website. Whenever a student fills out a quiz inside a lesson of a course, we execute a `submitQuiz` mutation. It resolves to an updated `Quiz` with a given grade. On top of that, submitting the quiz can also update the student's `progress` in the lesson and the overall `progress` in the course. Therefore, the `submitQuiz` mutation also resolves to a `Lesson` and `Course` with updated `progress`.

**Sample schema excerpt:**

```
type SubmitQuizResult: {
    Quiz: Quiz!
    Lesson: Lesson!
    Course: Course!
}

type Mutation {
    submitQuiz(quizId: Int!, answers: String!): SubmitQuizResult!
}
```

**How I call the mutation:**

```
mutation SubmitQuiz($quizId: Int!, $answers: String!) {
    submitQuiz(quizId: $quizId, answers: $answers) {
        Quiz { id answers grade }
        Lesson { id progress }
        Course { id progress }
    }
}
```

**Problem**:

Now, we want to add a new feature - counting time spent on our site. The timer would update any time the user does anything - checks and exercise, finishes reading a lesson or *submits a quiz*.

**Posible solutions:**

- Update code for all mutations to resolve to the *time-spent-on-our-site* timer
- Update code for all mutation calls to include a `refetchQueries` parameter which would refetch the current timer
- Use a subscription to push timer updates to the browser whenever the timer is updated

**Question:**

The docs say[1]:

> In the majority of cases, your client should not use subscriptions to
> stay up to date with your backend. Instead, you should poll
> intermittently with queries, or re-execute queries on demand when a
> user performs a relevant action.

When *should* one use subscriptions? Does my situation warrant their use?

---

[1] https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/#when-to-use-subscriptions